# How to replace content with javascript from Ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I wan't to replace a section from div in my index view with new data that I get from partial View. I get a correct responce, which I see in firebug. For now I only display on success an alert window, that says it's working. Bellow is my Ajax code and a part of response which i get(20 list-group items inside an ul). So do I have to write for every div javascript code just like in my view or is there another option? Maybe some examples please?

Regards!

```
<script>
        function testAjax() {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Content("~/Controller/MyAction")",
                data: "searchString=search",
                type: "Post",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    //Code for before send whatever you have to do.
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("It's Working!");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    //Your code when error ocure
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    //your code for failure
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
```

my response:

```
<ul class="list-group infinite-scroll">                       
        <li class="list-group-item col-md-6">
            <div class="noo-event-featured-item grow">
                <div class="sc-event-content">
                    <h3><a href="/Controller/Podrobnosti/73" onclick="checkCookie();">text</a></h3>
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <div class="create-date">
                            <span>
                                date
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sc-event-item">
                    <div class="event-thumbnail">
                        <a href="link" >
                            <img src="image link">
                        </a>
                        <div class="sc-meta">
                            <span class="sc-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span> text</span></span>
                            <span class="sc-address">
                                <i class="fa  fa-map-marker" style="padding-left: 3px;"></i>Place<span class="tribe-address">
                                    <span class="tribe-street-address">Street</span><span class="tribe-delimiter"
>, </span>
                                    <span class="tribe-locality">Country</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>               
            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is expected output ? What you want to manipulate ?

Comment: To replace my ul with the one i get from response.

Comment: If you want to replace your div entirely with the response html, you should try .replaceWith(data)  instead of .html(data).

Answer (score 0):

If your response its a html code(in plain text) you can try use something like this in your success function:

```
$('yourDiv').html(data);//replace child nodes
```

Comment: Sorry it' doesn't work for me :( The search function is working correctlly, I get another 20 results- infinate pagination, but first 20 results does not update. Do I have to modify the unobtrosive script. Or should I wrote some foreach function in the success method?

Comment: I get all the data in the alert window alert(data), but I can't figure it out how to replace data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I have figured it out. You have to use a dot before divid `$(".divid").replaceWith(data);`